# Protractor - compare numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, subtraction, end-to-end

In my program I'm calculating two numbers, and I want to make sure that subtraction of them equals 1.

this is the code:

```
var firstCount=element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps')).count();
var secondCount=element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps')).count();
```

so far it's good- I'm getting the numbers. the problem comes next:

```
var sub=secondCount-firstCount;
expect(sub).toEqual(1);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Expected NaN to equal 1.
```

any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `firstCount` and `secondCount` are **promises** that are **needed to be resolved**:

```
element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps')).count().then(function (first) {
    element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps')).count().then(function(second) {
        expect(first - second).toEqual(1);
    })
});
```

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the concept of 'promises' but it works! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to resolve only the first promise. Protractor adapts `expect` to "understand" promises. Refer https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#protractor-adaptations and https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/128.

```
element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps')).count().then(function (first) {
    // Do any changes here...
    var second = element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps')).count();
    // Here expect() resolves 'second'
    expect(second).toEqual(first + 1);
})
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You are doing absolutely right. But
Before comparison, Check whether your result value is number type or not.

Example-

```
expect(sub).toEqual(jasmine.any(Number));
```

Then perform an operation for expected conditions.