# How to convert "Promise <Number>" type to "Integer" type using "Protractor" tool

Tags: protractor

I have an `"Unordered list view"` in my Angular application which I need to automate, I want to retrieve the count of that list view using "Protractor" script.

I am using below code

```
var length = element.all(by.className('badge')).count();
```

Now i want to use above "Length" variable in "For loop" as below.

```
for(var i=0 ; i<length ; i++){}
```

then above "length" variable in "For loop" is displaying below error message.
Cannot be applied to types 'number' and Promise

So can anyone help me how to convert `"Promise <number>"` variable to `"integer"` variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor - compare numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076983/protractor-compare-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count()` returns a promise. Now you just need to resolve your promise. This will work for you

```
element.all(by.className('badge')).count().then(function(size){
    length = size;
    console.log(size.toString()); //if you like to see it

    //put the for loop code here within the then() as else your promise stays unresolved
});
```

find more about it in example [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2780) or in a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452454/how-to-click-on-button-until-a-dependent-value-reaches-a-certain-value).

Comment: Glad, I could help. Please mark the answer as the correct one, as it worked for you.